# Lazy loading properties after an insert

Tags: entity-framework

I have a parent and child object.  If I do the following

```
Child c = new Child();

c.ParentID = parentID;
context.Child.Add(c);
context.SaveChanges();

int i = c.Parent.ParentID; // throws an exception b/c Parent is null
```

Why is this doing this?  If I get a new context (after saving), I can see Parent just fine.

Comment: are you using EF 4.1 code first?

Comment: No.  We use EF, but not code first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: I set the foreign key, SaveChanges then access the navigation property, but it doesn't load the related entity. Why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552891/entity-framework-i-set-the-foreign-key-savechanges-then-access-the-navigation)

Comment: WHat will you do if context.Child is null ? I am getting null in my case, Any sugessions ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you are working with lazy loading enabled. If you want that the navigation property gets populated after adding the object with the foreign key property to the context you must use the `Create` method of `DbSet` (instead of instantiating the object with `new`):

```
Child c = context.Child.Create();
```

With active lazy loading this will create a proxy object which ensures that the navigation property gets loaded.

Comment: This explained why I couldn't navigate into any parent navigational properties when everything else I was reading suggested it should just work. Thanks.

Comment: @Slauma This is great, thank you. But how do I use the Create() method if my Child object has a constructor with required values? e.g. normally I would do Child c = new Child(OtherObject o). Obviously context.Child.Create(o) doesn't work.

Comment: @Jordan: It's not possible. `Create` can only instantiate an entity via a default constructor. You must set entity properties after calling `Create` (or call something like an `Init` method which you pass the parameters into).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late after the question but just to clarify. As MS docs states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/ef6/querying/related-data?redirectedfrom=MSDN#explicitly-loading), I use this instead:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var post = context.Posts.Find(2);

    // Load the blog related to a given post.
    context.Entry(post).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load();

    // Load the blog related to a given post using a string.
    context.Entry(post).Reference("Blog").Load();

    var blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);

    // Load the posts related to a given blog.
    context.Entry(blog).Collection(p => p.Posts).Load();

    // Load the posts related to a given blog
    // using a string to specify the relationship.
    context.Entry(blog).Collection("Posts").Load();
}
```

But it will work only if you use the Add() method

```
context.Set<T>().Add(post);
context.SaveChanges();
context.Entry(post).Reference(p => p.Blog).Load();
```

it will not work with .AddRange()