# Creating entity objects for insertion in Entity Framework 6

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Through examples in the past, I have learned to use `DbSet<TEntity>.Create()` to create entity objects for insertion.  However, I have found just using the default constructor with an object initializer seems to work just as well.

My main question is, do we ever still need to use `DbSet<TEntity>.Create()`, and why?

Bonus question: What, if any, is the functional difference between these two code examples?

"By the book":

```
    Dim db As New EFDAL.WidgetDbEntities()
    Dim dbWidgetBatch2 As EFDAL.WidgetBatch = db.WidgetBatches.Create()
    dbWidgetBatch2.CreationTimestamp = Now
    dbWidgetBatch2.CreatedByUsername = userName
    db.WidgetBatches.Add(dbWidgetBatch2)
    db.SaveChanges()
```

"Works just as well?":

```
    Dim db As New EFDAL.WidgetDbEntities()
    Dim dbWidgetBatch As New EFDAL.WidgetBatch With {
        .CreationTimestamp = Now,
        .CreatedByUsername = userName
    }
    db.WidgetBatches.Add(dbWidgetBatch)
    db.SaveChanges()
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311949/ramifications-of-dbset-create-versus-new-entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the duplicate candidate, I see the main subject matter of this question has already been covered.  However I feel it's worthwhile to summarize how the concepts apply to my question.

If I understand correctly, the short answer is that `DbSet.Create()` creates a "proxied" object which enables, among other things, lazy loading of navigation properties.

In the examples I posted, no navigation properties were used so both examples do in fact work equivalently, and for most inserts I suspect most people will not need a proxied object.

Links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx - Helped me understand proxying better
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504(v=vs.113).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) - Reference on `Dbset.Create()`

Comment: An alternative to using `DbSet.Create()` is using `Entry(model).Reference(o => MyRef).Load()` after `model` has been added to the DB context. For example: if `model.MyRefId` has a value then the corresponding entity of `model.MyRef` will be loaded. I find this useful when working with ASP.NET MVC applications and the out-of-the-box model binder.