# Entity Framework: I set the foreign key, SaveChanges then access the navigation property, but it doesn't load the related entity. Why not?

Tags: ef-code-first, lazy-loading, entity-framework-5

I am using this Entity class with Entity Framework 5 Code First:

```
public class Survey
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string SurveyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

And in my Controller's Create method I do this:

```
    Survey entity = new Survey()
    {
        SurveyName = "Test Name",
        ClientID = 4
    };
    db.Surveys.Add(entity);
    db.SaveChanges();
    Client c1 = entity.Client;                    //Why is this null?
    Client c2 = db.Clients.Find(entity.ClientID); //But this isn't?

    string s2 = c2.ClientName;
    string s1 = c1.ClientName;   //null reference thrown here
```

The Client navigation property remains null after SaveChanges. I expected the call to load the Client from the database because the foreign key exists. Why didn't it do that?

**EDIT**
The code here comes from when my controllers were dependent on `DbContext`. Not long after I got this working I re-factored the code to use repositories and a unit of work. Part of that move was driven by the fact that it just felt wrong to use `Create` when I wanted to use `new`. What happened then was that I hit a problem with [how to ensure proxies are created when using the repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736143/how-to-ensure-proxies-are-created-when-using-the-repository-pattern-with-entity).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To ensure that lazy loading of a navigation property will work after you've created the parent you must not create the `Survey` with the `new` operator but create it by means of the context instance because it will instantiate a dynamic proxy that is capable to lazily load the related `Client`. That's what the `DbSet<T>.Create()` method is for:

```
Survey entity = db.Surveys.Create();

entity.SurveyName = "Test Name";
entity.ClientID = 4;

db.Surveys.Add(entity);
db.SaveChanges();

Client c1 = entity.Client;
string s1 = c1.ClientName;
// will work now if a Client with ID 4 exists in the DB
```

Just to emphasize: It's not the line `entity.ClientID = 4;` or `db.Surveys.Add(entity);` or `db.SaveChanges` that loads the client from the DB, but the line `Client c1 = entity.Client;` (lazy loading).

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it pretty much tells me what I should be doing, but you should also read the answer from @nick_w. It really explains what the framework is doing.

Comment: BTW: I moved the db.Surveys.Add(entity); and db.SaveChanges(); lines right to the end and still got a null reference error. I had to put the db.Surveys.Add(entity); line before the access to the property to get lazy loading to work....so it appears that I have to use Create and Add

Comment: And to ensure that proxies are created when using the repository pattern. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16811976/150342

Comment: This is crazy-useful. Thank you VERY much!

Comment: Thank you! I hated having to use the .Include extension as it added a layer of complexity to my repository pattern that I felt should have happened automagically, and as stated using the new keyword was preventing lazy loading within the db context.So I used the Entity.Create() method ass you have in the example above and now all is well again in EF land.

Comment: A better way to ensure that proxies are created is if EF allowed you to make all your code first models abstract classes.

Comment: not supported anymore with EF Core for what I see. :(

Answer (score 11):

Like @NicholasButler said, calling `SaveChanges` does what it says on the tin - you can see this if you debug your code: the Intellitrace output will show the SQL it has generated for the insert/update you are persisting, but there will be no subsequent select.

Keep in mind that unless you are eager loading (using the `Include` method), related entities are not loaded when performing a retrieval, so it stands to reason that creating/updating them wouldn't either.

The Entity Framework (from I think versions 4.1 and up) supports lazy loading. What this means is that if it's enabled, code like `Client c1 = entity.Client;` *should* load up that `Client` object. To be clear, this operation is not directly related to the `SaveChanges` call.

It would pay to check whether `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` is set to `true`. If not, try setting it to be `true` and see if `Client c1 = entity.Client;` is still null.

In short, calling `SaveChanges` does not trigger a load, but if lazy loading is enabled, accessing `entity.Client` should trigger a load of the entity if it hasn't already been loaded.

**Edit:**

I should've though of this earlier, but you aren't going to be getting lazy loading on your `Survey entity` object. The reason is that EF works its lazy loading magic by creating a class derived from your one but overriding the properties marked as `virtual` to support lazy loading. It does this when you perform a retrieval, so your `entity` object will not lazy load anything as it stands.

Try this just after your call to `SaveChanges`:

```
Survey entity2 = db.Surveys.Find(entity.ID);
Client c1 = entity2.Client;
```

This should exhibit the behaviour you are after.

Comment: I'm using EF 5.0 and I've checked db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled is true but accessing entity.Client is still returning null I'm afraid. Must be something else...

Comment: Epiphany! "The reason is that EF works its lazy loading magic by creating a class derived from your one but overriding the properties marked as virtual to support lazy loading". Thank-you for that. One thing about this suggestion is that the Find after SaveChanges results in an extra database hit. I f

Comment: I found that if I fetched the Client first and assigned it to the navigation property, then that worked....I also like the look of Slauma's suggestion

Comment: My suggestion was really more to test whether lazy loading did what you want in this specific instance. Using the `Create()` method may be much more useful in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define all the properties on the `Survey` class as virtual to enable lazy-loading.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx for more information.

Comment: Unless I've missed something that only says that each navigation property must be declared as virtual. Nonetheless I tried what you said. I still get a null reference error.

Answer (score -1):

> I expected the call to load the Client from the database because the foreign key exists. Why didn't it do that?

It didn't do that because you haven't asked it to. After the call to `SaveChanges()`, EF doesn't have the data in the referenced row and it won't make a potentially redundant database call to get it.

Calling `db.Clients.Find(...` tells EF to go and fetch the row from the database, which is why it returns the object.

Comment: I thought Entity Framework automatically synchronised foreign keys and relationships? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: Loading the Client row would require a separate SQL call as you haven't loaded that data into the context. EF won't do that unless you tell it to.

Comment: If I set the "Client" navigation property it automatically populates the ClientID property (OK, it doesn't need a call to the database to do it). It just seems to me that it would make sense to make the call to the database if the foreign key has been set. Why is it "potentially redundant"?

Comment: Funny thing is the newly created object does automatically get its primary key field populated which does make it seem like data is being returned from the database.