# Inserted navigation property does not load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I've a class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

In the `User` Table:

```
Id    Name    
1     Tommy
2     John
```

I create an object:

```
Person P = new Person { Name = "Test", UserId = 1 };
```

I insert the `Person` object into the database:

```
db.Persons.Add(P);
db.SaveChanges();
var user = P.User;
```

The problem is if I try to access `P.User` it contains `null`. Other properties of `P` are populated properly.

Why?

Comment: Don't use ALLCAPS in titles, please.

Comment: Did you set user? It looks like you create a Person but don't associate the person with a  user - is the UserId supposed to do that? You've also got a lazy loaded (virtual) nav property, it might be worth profiling the SQL server to see what it tries to load when you access the property

Comment: Yes the UserId will do the association

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: I set the foreign key, SaveChanges then access the navigation property, but it doesn't load the related entity. Why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552891/entity-framework-i-set-the-foreign-key-savechanges-then-access-the-navigation)

Comment: And the solution I now use with the repository pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736143/how-to-ensure-proxies-are-created-when-using-the-repository-pattern-with-entity

Answer (score 2):

You should create the `Person` as follows:

```
Person p = db.Persons.Create();
p.Name = "Test";
p.UserId = 1;
```

The difference is that the `Person` is now created as a dynamic proxy, which means that it is capable of lazy loading. Once it is attached to the context (by `db.Persons.Add`) you can access the associated `User`.

Comment: I'm using repository & unit of work pattern, could you tell me how I can incorporate this?

Comment: Where have you got the `new Person` call now? It should be possible to replace that, I guess, since the repo should have a `DbContext` or a `DbSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark the UserId property as a foreign key like:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Like that, the entity framework will know that your `UserId` property is supposed to belong to the `User` property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute a new query for the person. An Entity Framework `insert` query will only return the id of the new object by using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, so the related objects aren't loaded. What if you do this:

```
var newPerson = db.Persons.Find(P.Id);
var user = newPerson.User;
```