# EF doesn't update related entities on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

I'm migrating my EF6 MVC project from ObjectContext to DbContext with lazy loading.

With ObjectContext, I could do the following:

```
// Create a new user:
 User u = new User();
 u.LineManagerID = 42;   // Set foreign key

 db.Users.Add(u);
 db.SaveChanges();

// get property of related entity as set above by foreign key 
 User lm = u.LineManager;
```

With DbContext, `u.LineManager` is null even the the new entity is saved correctly and I suspect if I did another call to the database it would be fine.

Lazy loading and dynamic proxies are both enabled.

Why doesn't the new entity refresh properly?

Please help! I can see this migration is going to be lot harder than I thought...!

**EDIT** - I should add that I am using db-first code generation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: I set the foreign key, SaveChanges then access the navigation property, but it doesn't load the related entity. Why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552891/entity-framework-i-set-the-foreign-key-savechanges-then-access-the-navigation)

Comment: I think you have to change to db.Users.Attached(user); then you have to tell it that you are updating something. It would be something like

db.Users.Attached(user);
db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

In addition, I don't believe that you have to manually tell it which   id to update. As long as you have a reference to that manager on your view. For example, if you have something like @html.EditorFor(model => model.Manager.Name) to capture the manager name, it should update the proper column. Hope I make sensse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to make the `LineManager` property `virtual` to be overridable by the lazy loading proxy. (which it already is thanks to the code generation)

When you are creating the object directly with `new` you are unfortunately just creating a plain object - not the proxy one with all the lazy loading features. To get those, you need to use a factory method to create your object:

```
User u = db.Users.Create();
```

I did some experimenting with navigation properties and foreign keys that I documented in a [blog post](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-code-first-navigation-properties-and-foreign-keys/).

Comment: Sorry Anders - just made some edits to my question which may change your answer.

Comment: Also I'm using db-first, so I shouldn't be adding `virtual` or anything else to the code that's auto-generated.

Comment: Well, that's right - I just updated my answer with a solution to the real problem - didn't see it first.

Comment: Excellent, clear explanation of the `new` thing. I can see your blog post is very helpful HOWEVER if anyone knows of a blog post that can help me migrate to DbContext from ObjectContext, that would be tremendous. I've had a google but couldn't find anything comprehensive.

Comment: Does this also mean that I can no longer populate the entity fields on construction e.g. `User u = new User() { Name="Joe" }`?

Comment: No, unfortunately you can't when using the factory method. The EF proxies are quite magic - but sometimes the magic fails to conceal what's going on underneath.

Comment: I've concealed the Create method inside my generic repository class in order to let me new up entities and keep the magic http://stackoverflow.com/a/16811976/150342